# pgfplots: Difference between xtick = {} and xtick = \empty (when extra x ticks are used)

Tags: pgfplots

- I generate a `xbar chart` in `pgfplots`.
- I specify `extra x ticks` but I do not want other `xticks`.
- `xtick = \empty` works.
- `xtick = {}` doesn't work.
- Is thsi an expected behaviour?

---

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xbar,
    symbolic y coords = {A,B,C,D,E},
    enlarge y limits = 0.15,
    ytick = data,
    width = 160mm,
    height = 90mm,
    xmin = 0,
    xmax = 10,
    extra x ticks={1},
    xtick = \empty,
    title = {\texttt{xtick = \textbackslash empty}},        
    ]
\addplot[fill=green] coordinates {(1,A) (2,B) (3,C) (4,D) (9,E)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xbar,
    symbolic y coords = {A,B,C,D,E},
    enlarge y limits = 0.15,
    ytick = data,
    width = 160mm,
    height = 90mm,
    xmin = 0,
    xmax = 10,
    extra x ticks={1},
    xtick = {},
    title = {\texttt{xtick = \{\}}},        
    ]
\addplot[fill=green] coordinates {(1,A) (2,B) (3,C) (4,D) (9,E)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: Documented behaviour, read the description of `xtick` in the manual.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Stupid me. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, this is documented behaviour, see the description of `xtick` in the manual:

[image]

Note that `xtick={}` is apparently the default, and that

> The initial configuration of an empty string means to generate these positions automatically.

Comment: I accept later -- I cannot accept it the next 8 min (says the pop-up). I leave the house now. Thanks for the help.